# svelte how does dollar sign know what variables it refers?

Tags: svelte

```js
<script>
    let count = 0;

    function handleClick() {
        count += 1;
    }
    $: {
        console.log('test'); // it is called once
        // console.log(count); it is called every time the count is changed
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Clicked {count} {count === 1 ? 'time' : 'times'}
</button>
```

I just wondered that how does svelte know what states is changed the dollar sign refers?

Svelte parses the code for that?

Answer (score 4):

> Svelte parses the code for that?

Yes, changes to state cause values to be invalidated and on update reactive statements are called if they contain any invalidated values. If you look at the compiled output, you will find something like this:

```js
    function handleClick() {
        $$invalidate(0, count += 1);
    }

    $$self.$$.update = () => {
        if ($$self.$$.dirty & /*count*/ 1) {
            $: {
                console.log(count);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer first. Do they parse the code as a string? Is it similar to like typescript, I mean like a transpiler? I wonder that syntax is also possible in javascript

Comment: Svelte is a transpiler. The syntax is valid in JS, but does nothing on its own. In JS it is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), which can be used in nested loops in combination with `continue`/`break`.

Comment: The way that it is transpiled means that something which calls a function but does not reference a variable won't work reactively.

`$: logCount();`
`function logCount() { console.log(count); }`


`logCount` would only be called once.